# Warning Message in R about <NA>

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data.frame in the form:

```
Set_1     Set_2     Set_3     Set_4     Set_5     Set_6     Set_7
1.42      0.98      <NA>      <NA>      0.98      2.91      0.40
<NA>      1.11      1.23      1.54      1.99      <NA>      <NA>
<NA>      1.02      0.99      <NA>      0.99      <NA>      1.00
<NA>      <NA>      1.88      0.87      0.32      0.55      1.33
```

I am trying to calculate a percentage of each column that is over 2.0

I am using the code `percent <- colSums(df > 2.0, na.rm=TRUE)/colSums(!is.na(df))`

but I keep getting the warning message: `In Ops.factor(left, right) : > not meaningful for factors`. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your columns to `numeric`, then proceed with percents

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
sapply(dat, function(x) sum(x>2, na.rm=T)/nrow(dat))
```

A useful way to check your column types is

```
sapply(dat, class)
```

Also, as @RichardScriven pointed out, you can get rid of the annoying warnings during the conversion with

```
dat[] <- suppressWarnings(lapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
```

Comment: When I used your top line `dat[ ] <- lapply(dat, as.numeric)` it changed my decimals all to whole value integers of varying magntidue.

Comment: @Evan yes, Im sorry I hadnt tested that, as RichardScriven noted, you need to conver factor->character->numeric

Comment: The output is different than the one got with OP's code.  I think the OP is trying to remove the observations that are `NA` in the denominator.. i.e `colSums(dat>2, na.rm=TRUE)/colSums(!is.na(dat))`